# Failed to allocate an array of pointers to a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to allocate an array of pointers to a struct but there's something wrong with my code.

This is my struct:

```
struct Brick {
  GameObject2D* handle_;
};

Brick** bricks_;
```

And this is how i'm trying to allocate memory for it:

```
int bricks_amount_ = 10;    

bricks_ = (Brick**)malloc(sizeof(Brick*) * bricks_amount_);
```

The program crash. I've make a devenv on it to debug where's the problem and it crash on this line:

```
for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < bricks_amount_; i++){
  bricks_[i]->handle_ = new GameObject2D(); <---------- CRASH!
}
```

Any suggestions?

*PS: Sorry for my english :P*

=========================================================================

[SOLUTION]

Finally i've decided to use std::vector instead raw pointers:

```
bricks_.resize(bricks_amount_);
```

but i've tried to make the malloc different way and it works too:

```
bricks_ = (struct Brick*)malloc(sizeof(struct Brick) * bricks_amount_);
```

or this:

```
bricks_ = new Brick[bricks_amount_];
```

Thank you to the people who wants to help!

Comment: Clearly `bricks_[i]->handle_` accesses uninitialized memory. `bricks_[i]` hasn't been assigned a value.

Comment: Also don't mix `malloc()` and `new()`, use `new []` for allocating arrays.

Comment: Additional explanation to @KerrekSB' comment (+1): malloc creates a usable array, but the contents are uninitialized, meaning that your Brick* pointers are all at a completly random value, possibly null, possibly pointing to beyond the stars... What you missed was `game_state_.bricks_[i] = new Brick();`, e. g. right before your crash, to initialize each pointer within the array.

Comment: Why all the pointers? Why _any_ pointers?

Comment: Life gets much simpler if you stop using raw pointers

Comment: @M.M But even with e. g. ::std::unique_ptr, you still have to assign a newly created Brick instance to it - lack of which caused the actual error...

Comment: @Aconcagua this example seems better suited to `vector`

Comment: @M.M `vector<Brick>`, then. Critical due to possible reallocations, however, if needing pointers (raw or not) to the bricks from elsewhere. Pity we do not know TO's requirements...

Comment: I'm gonna try to use std::vector, because for objects i have no problem, but with struct yes...

Comment: @tonimarquez84 What is the difference between an object and a struct..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's C++:

- don't use `malloc`, use `new`
- don't use plain arrays, use `std::vector` or `std::array`
- don't use raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Something like this: bricks_ = new Brick [bricks_amount_];

Answer (score -1):

Do not use

```
Bricks **   //will be a 2 dimensional array
```

Use instead

```
Bricks *   //will be a 1 dimensioanal array
```

If you want a single dimensional array

Then do

```
`Bricks * bricks_  = (Bricks *)malloc(sizeof(Brick) * bricks_amount_ );

`
```

Then you can safely do without a crash

```
for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < bricks_amount_; i++){


bricks_[i]->handle_ = new GameObject2D(); <----------   There will not be CRASH!
}
```

Comment: This is not correct - using malloc, you still get an unitialized array (that needs to be initialized via placement constructor!). Additionally, this way, you need to use `bricks[i].handle_` then.

Comment: Yup @Aconcagua you are correct, These are still unitialized pointers, but if the struct is containing only 1 pointer and these will be alloacted with new in the very next step , then its fine.

Comment: Still you circumvented the contstructor (remember, this is C++), and if ever the Brick class changes (more precise: receives non POD members), you might get into trouble (OK, you still can call the appropriate placement constructors for each member of type ::std::string, ::std::vector or whatever else class ::myNamespace::MyClass is used - and change your loop every time the Brick class changes).

Comment: It just looks like one - but the Bricks actually are never created because of using malloc instead of new Brick[n], which would call the constructor.

Comment: @Aconcagua , yes you are right but his Bricks object contains only a pointer which will be set in the next set of instructions.  This solution will only work when Bricks objects remains same as the way it is right now.

Comment: @ATulSingh You pushed me towards an interesting [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37644977/1312382) concerning undefined behaviour. Apparently, in the current case, it is OK, but as soon as a constructor is added to the class, we receive UB...

Comment: @ATulSingh Have to correct myself - the mentioned thread evolves more and more, and it seems to be undefined behaviour even for POD objects.