# Is taking uninitialized references of class members during construction legal?

Tags: c++

Coming from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37644977/1312382), I am going a step further:

```cpp
C* c = static_cast<C*>(malloc(sizeof(C)));
```

As stated in the referenced question, accessing *c (its members) is undefined behaviour before a constructor is called. But, the pointer itself is valid, of course.

Now within the constructor, the members are available already and I should be able to take the address off.

Putting this together, I conclude that the following is legal:

```cpp
class Y;
class X
{
    Y& y;
public:
    X(Y& y) : y(y) { } // non-trivial constructor!
};
class Y
{
    X& x;
public:
    Y(X& x) : x(x) { }
};
class Z
{
    X x;
    Y y;
public:
    Z() : x(y), y(x) { } 
};
```

as long as the constructor of X does not use the uninitialized reference to Y other than storing it somewhere.

Is this correct or have I overseen some important point (and thus producing UB again)? If I missed something, would it make a difference if I used pointers instead of references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine, but you are not allowed to use `y` inside of `X(Y& y)` as it was not yet initialized.

The relevant part that says it is not UB is:

3.7.5/6 n4140 (emphasis is mine)

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the
>   storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the
>   lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>   object occupied is reused or released, ***any glvalue that refers to the
>   original object may be used but only in limited ways***.

`y` is lvalue (which is also a glvalue), so above is relevant here. Accessing variables using such reference is UB.

Standard also says that reference to be valid it must (8.3.2/5):

> ... A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.

But I have not found in standard what is `valid object`. Especially whether it means that its constructor has already been called. Using pointer instead of reference seems to not have this problem.

Comment: See my question, 'as long as'... I provided the malloc-and-cast example for having an equivalence to something already known - in both cases, I have a valid pointer to memory that has not yet been initialized. Well, second case (my question): at least, if I concluded correctly, of course. The equivalence is not to Z, but to its member y (of type Y).

Comment: @Aconcagua so you are asking if (as example) doing `y.c = 123;` inside of    X constructor would cause UB? I suppose standard is clear here: this is what `limited ways` explains, among others: UB is if `(5.2) — the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the
object, or`

Comment: But those rules applies as I understand when you use for example `new`, when `malloc` is used constructor will not be called anyway.

Comment: Using c->someMember before the (placement) constructor is called is UB, same as if X(Y& y) used y.someMember. This point is clear and was *not* intended to ask either. Sorry if I expressed myself badly. But c (the pointer itself is valid), so I could do `C* cc = c;` without UB. Question then is, if this applies for the reference to an uninitialized member (Z::y) during construction of an object, too.

Comment: @Aconcagua see my edit, its not more about references instead of pointers

Answer (score 2):

This is legitimate. To justify this, see the following from the standard, [basic.life]:

> 5. Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
>    which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the
>    lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>    object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the
>    storage location where the object will be or was located may be used
>    but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or
>    destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a pointer refers to allocated
>    storage (3.7.4.2), and using the pointer as if the pointer were of
>    type void*, is well-defined. ...
>
> ...
>
> 6. Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the
>    storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the
>    lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>    object occupied is reused or released, **any glvalue that refers to the
>    original object may be used but only in limited ways.** For an object
>    under construction or destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a glvalue
>    refers to allocated storage (3.7.4.2), and using the properties of the
>    glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined.
>
> ...

Merely taking a reference falls under the 'limited use' (for objects whose lifetime has not yet begun) criteria set out above.