# How to extend an inherited class's inherited class

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this minimal example:

```
class BaseClass {
    void method1();
};

class Foo : public BaseClass {
    void method1();
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    void method1();
}

class Interface : public Foo {
};

class MyClass : public Interface, public Bar {
}
```

When implementing `MyClass`, how can I tell the compiler that `Bar` is extending the `Foo` in `Interface`? I keep getting compiler errors due to the ambiguous conversion.

Note: `Foo` and `Bar` are from a library, so I can't implement another interface just to handle this.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual inheritance?

Comment: I don't know, am I?

Comment: @iHowell It would appear you are. Sorry about that.

Comment: Some helpful reading: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance

Comment: @iHowell Yes, you are... MyClass inherits two instances of `Foo`: one from `Interface` and one from `Bar`. If you only want a single instance in `MyClass`, both `Interface` and `Bar` need to inherit from `Foo` virtually.

Comment: But, as I said, I don't actually have access to `Foo` or `Bar`, so what else could I do? I only have access to `Interface` and `MyClass`.

Comment: You might avoid `Interface` inheriting from `Foo`. Why did you do so at all?

Comment: So, `Foo` and `Bar` are the classes `QAbstractItemModel` and `QAbstractListModel` (from the Qt library) respectively. `Interface` needs to be a generic model, while `MyClass` should use the list model. I might just be able to make `MyClass` implement the list model though, without directly inheriting from it.

Comment: And you cannot entirely replace `Interface` with `QAbstractItemModel`? What does `Interface` provide as extra?

Comment: Interface is used as a factory type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177667/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-ihowell).

Comment: @iHowell i am not getting any compiler errors so ☺read this tutorial first you get answer  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm

Comment: @anilsinghbutola It is not about a compile error, but about (unwanted!) double inheritance of Foo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() { }
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "foo!" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void f() override { std::cout << "bar!" << std::endl; }
};
```

Problem now is that you cannot inherit from `Foo` in `Interface`:
You cannot modify `Bar`, thus you cannot make it inherit virtually, so even if `Interface` did, you'd get two instances of `Foo` in `MyClass`. So my approach is having a reference to Foo within interface and provide an explicit cast to:

```
class Interface
{
    Foo& foo;
protected:
    Interface(Foo& foo) : foo(foo) { }
public:
    operator Foo&()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    virtual ~Interface() { }

    // this actually is only a short cut - you can always
    // access Foo's f via cast as well!
    // (so you can drop it, if you prefer)
    virtual void f() { foo.f(); }
};

class MyClass : public Interface, public Bar
{
public:
    MyClass() : Interface(*static_cast<Foo*>(this)) { }
    using Bar::f;
};
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
MyClass c;
Interface* i = &c;
Foo* f = &static_cast<Foo&>(*i);
// or, if you have not yet lost access to c, simply:
f = &static_cast<Foo&>(c);
```

Extension: If you need to be able to instantiate `Interface` directly (not in form of a derived class), you can achieve this with some minor modifications to `Interface`:

```
class Interface
{
    Foo* foo; // raw pointer even in times of C++11 and smart pointers:
              // need to be able to delete  c o n d i t i o n a l l y
    bool isOwner;
protected:
    Interface(Foo& foo) : foo(&foo), isOwner(false) { }
public:
    Interface() : foo(new Foo()), isOwner(true) { }

    operator Foo&()
    {
        return *foo;
    }

    virtual ~Interface()
    {
        if(isOwner)
        {
            delete foo;
        }
    }

    virtual void f() { foo->f(); }
};
```

*Edit:* While above would work in general, you would get in trouble if you try to delete an `Interface` (not derived) via `Foo` pointer. You can solve the issue as follows:

```
class Interface
{
    Foo& foo;
protected:
    Interface(Foo& foo) : foo(foo) { }
public:

    operator Foo&()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    virtual ~Interface() { }

    //virtual void f() { foo.f(); }
};

class MyFoo : public Interface, public Foo
{
public:
    MyFoo() : Interface(*static_cast<Foo*>(this)) { }
    virtual ~MyFoo() { }
    //using Foo::f; // don't need, if dropping the short cut
};

class MyBar : public Interface, public Bar
{
public:
    MyBar() : Interface(*static_cast<Foo*>(this)) { }
    virtual ~MyBar() { }
    //using Bar::f; // don't need, if dropping the short cut
};
```

While now `Foo` inherits from `Bar`, `MyBar` does not from `MyFoo`, so you cannot assign a `MyBar` object to a `MyFoo` pointer. But you can both assign (via the cast) to a `Foo` pointer, which is, according to the discussion to question, your actual goal, so this should be fine...

Comment: @anilsinghbutola All in all, with verifying and testing, something around 3/4 hour...

Comment: There is one potential issue with passing `this` to parent constructor, as `this` is not yet fully constructed. According to a former [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37724668/1312382), this should be fine, though.

Comment: its look fine to me also

Comment: @Aconcagua, I think it's fine because you're passing a reference.

Comment: @iHowell That was consensus in answers to my question as well, posted the comment rather as confirmation than as question. It's just that standard sometimes is very strict about such matters, and although some constructions work with *any* compiler available on *any* hardware available, they still are UB. So before questions arise...

Comment: @Aconcagua, if I need there to be a public constructor for `Interface`, since a factory is creating instances of `Interface`, how would I provide a public constructor, since I wouldn't have the `Foo` yet?

Comment: @iHowell You are referring to my last edit (MyFoo and MyBar)? Then you won't ever create `Interface` directly! If you need a bare Foo Interface, you'd create MyFoo, if a Bar Interface, MyBar, if another Interface, MyAnother. As I mentioned already, you are losing the inheritance between MyFoo and MyBar, don't get irritated by.

Comment: @iHowell If you still need such inheritance, you need another parallel hierarchy: `Interface`, `InterfaceFoo : public Interface`, `InterfaceBar : public FooInterface`, `MyFoo : public FooInterface, public Foo`, `MyBar : public BarInterface, public Bar`. Hm, did not try, actually, you should even be able to inherit privately from `Foo` and `Bar`, by which you could prevent a wild mix between the Interface hierarchy and the Foo/Bar one...

Comment: @iHowell Yep, you can... But then before you can cast to `Foo`, you need to cast to `Interface` before, if you want to cast a `MyFoo` or `MyBar` (or pointer to).