# Circular dependencies in C++ classes using references

Tags: c++

I have two objects of classes (A and B) which must be able to refer to each other, e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
    A(B& b);

private:
    B& b;
};

class B {
public:
    B(A& a);

private:
    A& a;
};
```

But I can't do this:

```
A a(b);
B b(a);
```

With pointers this would be easy, as a pointer can be NULL. How can I achieve the same result using references, or is it not possible?

Comment: Forward declarations and separating header + source or think your design over.

Comment: @nada that doesn't cover the actual construction of the objects, though.

Comment: Yes, the construction of the objects is point I can't get past.

Comment: Regarding the construction, it's not simply possible with your current design and implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to pack both of them into third object and initialize at constructor:

```
class C
{
    public: A m_a;
    public: B m_b;

    public: C(void): m_a{m_b}, m_b{m_a} {}
};
```

Note that this approach requires class `A` not to access passed reference to class `B` at constructor because object `B` is not initialized at that point.

Comment: Isn't that an UB? passing uninitialized `m_b` to the constructor of `m_a`?

Comment: @Quest Accessing passed reference will be UB, but just passing a reference (or a pointer) is not.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Quest Actually, that has been asked in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724668/is-taking-uninitialized-references-of-class-members-during-construction-legal) already...