# Is it UB to placement new &data[i] instead of data + i?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic, placement-new

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <string>
struct S { std::string str; };

int main() {
    S *data = static_cast<S*>(operator new(sizeof(S) * 3));
    new (&data[1]) S();  // (1)
    new (data + 2) S();  // (2)
    data[2].~S();  // (3)
    data[1].~S();  // (4)
    operator delete(data);
}
```

My understanding is that lines (2)-(4) have perfectly valid behavior.

However, I'm not sure about line `(1)`: on the one hand, I never access the non-existing object `data[1]` because I only need its address. On the other hand, I do by writing `data[1]`, thus possibly invoking undefined behavior.

Is `&data[1]` defined when `data` is an allocated chunk of memory, but there is no object or subobject at `data + 1`?

Comment: Aside why `operator new` and `operator delete`?

Comment: @Caleth No particular reason. C++-isher than `malloc`/`free` and I have not used `std::allocator` much.

Comment: I mean instead of `new` and `delete`

Comment: @Caleth So I get raw memory, not an array of initialized objects like in `new S[3]`. `new (3)` is not valid C++.

Comment: IMHO raw memory might not be aligned sufficiently. Might want to use aligned_storage at line 0.

Comment: You didn't specify the standard version. In standards prior to C++20, your code have underspecified behavior at best, in C++20 you have array `S[3]` in the allocated memory (even though the lifetime of elements of this array is not started).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer You mean, `new (data + 2) S()` is not great prior to C++20 as well, don't you?

Comment: @rustyx allocation function shall allocate storage suitable for any non-extended alignment object https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#3.3

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Do you mean to say `std::string` is guaranteed to not use extended alignment? The provided example looks contrived, anyway.

Comment: _You mean, new (data + 2) S() is not great prior to C++20 as well, don't you?_ Something like this. If you use an expression of type "pointer to `T`" in pointer arithmetic, it'd better to actually point to object of type [similar to] `T` (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#6)

Comment: @rustyx `new` guarantees that an allocation of `n` bytes is correctly aligned for an object of size `n` or larger.

Comment: @MartinYork That's unless the object uses `alignas` internally. See [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#3.3)

Comment: @rustyx See: `n4868` Section: `7.6.2.8 New` paragraph 15.

Comment: @rustyx Does `S`?  `A new-extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`'?

Comment: @MartinYork Probably not, but as I said in another comment earlier, the example looks contrived, and in real life `S` just might.

Answer (score 4):

If the operators in question have not been overloaded to mean something different, `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`. Somewhat amusingly also `y[x]` due to `+` being commutative.

In your example, `&data[1]` is an exact equivalent of `data+1` and equally well-defined. UB would be reading the uninitialized memory, taking its address is not.

Comment: That leaves the question whether `&*x` is valid whenever `x` is a valid pointer, but does not point to a valid object. Looks like [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724668/is-taking-uninitialized-references-of-class-members-during-construction-legal)

Comment: @yeputons What is _valid object_?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer No idea, actually. I'm not sure what formalism goes here.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I take that to mean an object whose lifetime has been correctly started but not ended.