# What is exactly an object in C++?

Tags: c++, object

In the beginning of my journey learning C++, I thought an object is an OOP-only related term. However, the more I learn and the more I read, I can see that this not the case, and I can find that the term "object" has a more generalized meaning. I read a lot of materials on the net, but I could not yet find something clear/solid. May be I could not get to the correct place. I could get the standards and it has good paragraphs about this, but as you may know standard language is a bit difficult. and the information usually too scattered.

My question: would you please show me in a simple English **What is an object in C++ outside the OOP world?**

Comment: Something that has an address in memory.

Comment: read, for example, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: Wow, Great source. How come I did not come to this page before?! Thanks a million @Stephan Lechner.

Comment: @KamalZidan.. Anonymous downvotes are sth you have to get used to if you want to spend some time in SO. Just ignore them and go on (unless they are more than 1 Downvote/Sec then there is sth horribly wrong with your question)

Comment: Thanks @Humam Helfawi. This was a great thing to know.

Comment: A region of storage with associated semantics. this is from isocpp super faq.

from element of programming:
 Object: A representation of a concrete entity as a value in memory. An object is changeable and has a computer-specific implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `C++11` standard is pretty clear:

> **1.8** The C ++ object model **[** intro.object **]**
>
> An object is a region of storage. [ Note: A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do. — end note ]

That's it. An object is a chunk of memory in which data can be stored.

If you think about it **OO** or **O**bject **O**rientation makes more sense when you realize that in the old days the programs were organized around the functions which operated upon the objects (or data).

The term "object" was around *long* before *object orientation*.

What *object orientation* did was change the program organization from being organized around the functions to being organized around the data itself - the *objects*.

Hence the term **object orientated**.

**Change of paradigm**.

Here we see the paradigm shift from the old days:

```
struct my_object
{
    int i;
    char s[20];
};

void function(my_object* o)
{
    // function operates on the object (procedural / procedure oriented)
}
```

To what we have now:

```
struct my_object
{
    void function()
    {
        // object operates on itself (Object Oriented)
    }

    int i;
    char s[20];
};
```

Comment: That's a much broader definition than I would have expected from C++. It even would apply to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @MarkRansom "uninitialized" or "unused"? As far as the standard (and the abstract machine it describes) goes, unused memory doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I mean for example something returned by `malloc`.

Comment: @MarkRansom mmh, true.

Comment: Maybe every object is a region of storage, but not every region of storage is an object ;)

Comment: You could consider a `malloc`'d region of storage as an object IMO. Maybe not a particularly useful one, but you would still work with it just like every other object. The only difference between a `void*` and `myclass*` is that `myclass*` has something useful I can do with it. I could still work with a block of memory just the same, but maybe not in an object-oriented manner.

Comment: @rwols According to the standard, even uninitialized storage is referred to as an object.

Comment: Due to its incompleteness this answer is realy close to be wrong. Referring to the same paragraph of the standard one can read that an object: occupies a **region of storage**, has a **life time**, has a **storage duration**, has a **type** -> the **object type** (which is unique). It also has a periode of construction and a period of destruction.

Answer (score 7):

#### Short answer

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.object

> An object is a region of storage.

---

#### A slightly longer answer

In traditional OOP and OOD, an Object is used to describe class of objects some times and to an instance of a class some times.

In C++, `class` and `struct` represent classes.

An object in C++ can be an instance of a `class` or a `struct` but it can also be an instance of a fundamental type.

**A few simple examples:**

```
int i;
```

`i` is an object. It is associated with a region of storage that can be used by the program.

```
struct foo { int a; int b;};
foo f;
```

`f` is an also object. It is also associated with a region of storage that can be used by the program.

```
int* ptr = new int[200];
```

`ptr` is a pointer that points to 200 objects of type `int`. Those objects are also associated with a region of storage that can be used by the program.

Answer (score 7):

Not to bash on the existing answers, but they're missing an element (that's arguably a standard defect).

> An *object* is a region of storage. [ *Note:* A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do.  — *end note* ]
>
> An object is created by a *definition* ([basic.def]), by a *new-expression* ([expr.new]) or by the implementation ([class.temporary]) when needed.
>
> The properties of an object are determined when the object is created.

An object is a region of storage *in which constuction has taken place*. In fact, most of the time "object" refers to that constructed entity, with its value and state, whereas "storage" just means the memory (or whatever) it is written on.

The difference can be a simple detail:

```
// `s` names an object that has been constructed... somewhere.
// That storage will live exactly as long as necessary to back `s`
// as long as the object exists -- no need to worry about it.
std::string s = "hello";

// Using the object
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

But you can also (although it's very rarely useful) separate the object's lifetime from the lifetime of its storage:

```
// `storage` points at a chunk of... storage.
// It hasn't been initialized, nor does it have a type.
void *storage = malloc(sizeof(std::string));

// Now we constructed an `std::string`:
// we have an actual object inhabiting the storage!
std::string *s = new (storage) std::string("hello");

// Using the object, through the pointer we have
std::cout << *s << '\n';    

// Now we destruct the object: it exists no more.
s->~basic_string();

// Now we destroy the storage.
free(storage);
```

I must stress that this last example is for demonstration purposes only. It's a technique you probably won't encounter, and has been performed here with no error checking whatsoever. Don't try this at home :)

Now, how does it relate to the OOP "object"? Well... not at all. "Object" is a *very* generic term, and OOP founders just chose to use it as well, independently.

Comment: "An object is a region of storage in which constuction has taken place." - That would seem to imply that given `int n;`, then `n`  is not an object.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it is: it's a default-constructed `int`. Construction does not imply initialization for trivially-constructible types :)

Comment: @Quentin In the case of `int n;` nothing has taken place in the region occupied by `n`, construction or otherwise.

Comment: @Galik I'm struggling with my sentence. I just mean that both groups (C++ and OOP) had to name two completely different concepts, and they both settled on "object" because they found it fitting. Hence, a vocabulary collision, made more probable by the vagueness of "object" as a word. If you can come up with better wording, feel free to edit :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but [dcl.init] (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#6) provides a bullet point precisely about (airquotes) "non-initializing initialization".

Comment: @Galik I'm admittedly a bit rusty on my OOP, but I seem to recall that an "object" there is a modeled entity, along with its state, associated functions, invariants, etc. -- much more than just a piece of storage. IOW, a dumb `int` is a C++ object, but not an OOP object.

Comment: In the case where  `n` is a local variable, some space for it is allocated on the stack when the function containing it starts, and that's it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth of course nothing is actually *done* at the machine level in an optimized build, but this is still conceptually a construction. Debug runtimes may also initialize it to some recognizable value.

Comment: note that based on [p0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) an object can be also be created _in some cases_ using malloc. See also: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61999151/2085626)

Answer (score 5):

Refering to §1.8 of the c++ standard (N4618), an object:

1. occupies a **region of storage** during its *period of construction*, through its *lifetime* and its *period of destruction*;
2. has a **lifetime** (for non trivial objects it start when initialization is completed and stop when the destructor starts);
3. has a **storage duration** (static, dynamic, thread or automatic)
4. has a **type**: the *object type* which is unique (strict aliasing).
5. *may* have a **name**

---

#### About object type

(Other answers already have detailed the meaning of storage duration.)

The *object type* (or class) is a unique property of an object. The *object type* specifies the meaning of the region of storage occupied by the initialized object. So the meaning is unique, from a philosophical point of view, the *object type* is the species of the object, not its kind.

For the **compiler**, it only constrains the ensemble of operation that can be applied to the region of storage: the methods associated to the object type (in which case the type is defined by `class` or `struct`), and all the functions taking the object as an argument (which are visible).

For the **programmer**, the type also specifies what will be the consequences of the application of a sequence of operations to the object during its *lifetime*. The type contains much more information than the compiler actualy may be able to know. For exemple after having checked that the size of an object, `an_obj` of type `std::vector<int>` is `0`, the programmer knows that `an_obj.at(0)` will always throw, the compiler may not.

Answer (score -5):

In C++ world, an object is the instantiation of a class. It behaves (methods/functions) in certain ways and has attributes (data members) that depicts its state.

An object has lifetime. It is created (through constructor), it lives, and it dies (through destructor).

A class is like a blueprint, through which you define the behavior and attribute of an object.

Comment: Unlike other languages, "object" in C++ does not necessarily refer to an instance of a class. An `int` is an object.