# How does the computer make sure that a member only can be accessed though an object?

Tags: c++

How does the computer make sure that a member of a structure cannot be accessed without using an object of that structure?
Maybe this badly worded, so here is an example:
We have this struct:

```
struct products 
{
int a;
int b;
} apples;
```

This can only be accessed through an object of the structure, which in this case is `apples`:

```
int main ()
{
apples.a = 20; //the member a can be accessed through apples and a would be another variable if accessed through another object, why is that?
return 0;
}
```

Same goes for classes...
So how does the computer(not sure what is handling this) make sure that `products`'s members can only be accessed through an object of that struct or class(type)?

Thanks!

Comment: Computers deal with zeroes and ones, they don't care about how you access stuff. It's the compiler's job. If you do it the "wrong" way (against the rules of the _language_), the compiler warns you or throws an error at you

Comment: Well, of course apples.a means the a of apples, and pears.a means something else so it won't access the a of apples... how can that not be clear? ... If you mean at runtime, the computer does not make sure. It's entirely possible, and a valid use case, to access a without having "apples.a" in the code.

Comment: All that fancy `struct products {} apples;` thing is just "meh" for the computer as it doesn't understand it. It has only been created for _you_, a human, to use. All these concepts of objects, `struct`s, classes, integers, `double`s and stuff - all of this is _just for you to understand and work with_, the computer doesn't care.

Comment: @deviantfan that said, the vmm of the OS should prevent you from runtime egregious violations at runtime, let trying to access addresses that mapped to your process.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43946981/990142

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you need an instance of the struct/class in order to access
the members of the struct/class

When you write

```
struct products
{
  int a；
  int b;
} apples;
```

you declare an instance of the struct products in memory (depends on where the declaration is)

```
 +---+---+
 | a | b |
 +---+---+
```

writing just

```
 struct products
 {
   int a;
   int b;
 };
```

does not create an instance of the struct, instead you have told the 
 compiler that there is a struct called products that has two members a and b
 the struct is in effect a type.

Answer (score 0):

The class members are created when an object is instantiated. The exception to this fact is when a member is defined statically (with the prefix "static" in front of the declaration). In this case the static member is available also when no object is not instantiated. An example:

```
class A {
static int x;
int y;
};
```

In this case you can access x without having an object, e.g.

```
A::x = 7;
```

Notice the different syntax when accessing a static member...

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
int main() {
    apples obj1;
    apples obj2;
}
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are distinct objects: they exist in different parts of the memory, i.e. `&obj1 != &obj2`. Then, assuming that `int` is 4-byte type, `obj1.a` would be the int at `&obj1 + 0` and `obj1.b` the int at `&obj1 + 4 bytes` and `obj2.b` the int at `&obj2 + 4 bytes`.

The compiler is responsible for converting names ("obj1" and "obj2") into memory locations. (That is, as far as the stack is concerned.)

*p.s.* That's about objects. Not sure if you're asking about classes instead. In this case the answer is that when you write `a`, this is an *unqualified name*. The compiler, depending on the context (i.e. if it's in the body a member function of class `Apple` or if you are writing `my_apple_object.a`) will know that you're actually referring to `Apple::a` and not to `Blueberry::a`. Likewise if the same `a` token appeared in the body of a member function of `Blueberry`, the compiler would know that you're referring to `Blueberry::a`. And if the context is ambiguous the compiler will complain and/or issue an error.

Comment: `&obj1 + 4` is out of bounds , you're mixing up pointers with integers

Comment: It may be overly simplified. `* (int*) ( (char*)&obj1 + 4 )` would often be the same as `obj1.b`

Answer (score 0):

`struct` and `class` both provide access restrictions in the form of `private:`, `public:`, and `protected:`. Anything you declare behind one of the qualifiers becomes just that.

- `public` means you can access it the way you specified - no protection;
- `protected` means only the class and classes derived from it can access it;
- `private` means only the class itself can access it.

The only difference between `struct` and `class` is that `struct` starts with the default set to `public:`, and `class` starts with `private:` active. You can change the setting anywhere in the class definition, at the beginning or between declarations, for example:

```
struct products
{
  private:
    int a；
    int b;
} apples;
```

makes `a` and `b` inaccessible from outside the class.