# Calling methods of unconstructed objects: Legal?

Tags: c++, c++11

If memory is set aside for an object (e.g., through a union) but the constructor has not yet been called, is it legal to call one of the object's non-static methods, assuming the method does not depend on the value of any member variables?

I researched a bit and found some information about "variant members" but I couldn't find info pertaining to this example.

```
class D {
 public:
  D() { printf("D constructor!\n"); }
  int a = 123;
  void print () const {
    printf("Pointer: %p\n", &a);
  };
};

class C {
 public:
  C() {};
  union {
    D memory;
  };
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.memory.print();
}
```

In this example, I'm calling print() without the constructor ever being called. The intent is to later call the constructor, but even before the constructor is called, we know where variable *a* will reside. Obviously the value of *a* is uninitialized at this point, but print() doesn't care about the value.

This seems to work as expected when compiling with gcc and clang for c++11. But I'm wondering if I'm invoking some illegal or undefined behavior here.

Comment: Eh? `C c;` constructs `c`.

Comment: @user207421 but it does not construct `c.memory` because that is a variant member for which the constructor of `C` does not provide an initializer…

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is undefined behavior. Your variant member `C::memory` has not been initialized because the constructor of `C` does not provide an initializer [[class.base.init]/9.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9.2). Therefore, the lifetime of `c.memory` has not begun at the point where you call the method `print()` [[basic.life]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1). Based on [[basic.life]/7.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#basic.life-7.2):

> Similarly, **before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated** or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. […] **The program has undefined behavior if**:
>
> - […]
> - **the glvalue is used to call a non-static member function of the object**, or
> - […]

emphasis mine

Note: I am referring to the [current C++ standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/) above, however, the relevant wording is basically the same for C++11 except that, in C++11, the fact that `D` has non-trivial initialization is crucial as what you're doing may otherwise potentially be OK in C++11…

Comment: The fact that `D` has non-trivial initialization is also important here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Please correct me if I'm wrong, but since `memory` is a variant member, its lifetime should never begin without an explicit intialization being performed, the fact that it has non-trivial initialization doesn't seem to me to have an influence in this particular case!?

Comment: If it has trivial initialization, its lifetime begins the moment (properly sized and aligned, etc) storage is allocated.

Comment: Ah, the wording in your link `[basic.life]/1` is *very* different from C++11.  Applicable wording: "The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete."

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed, that is very interesting. It would seem that the wording has changed to the current form in C++17. I wonder if that won't break some code as the new wording would seem to be a non-conservative change from the pervious one…

Comment: I wonder if the intended interpretation of the new wording is that vacuous initialization is never incomplete, so again objects not scheduled for non-vacuous initialization begin life as soon as storage is obtained.

Comment: @BenVoigt so that means that, if `D` had trivial initialization, it would seem to be OK to call a member function on it in C++11 while in C++17 it may not be!?

Comment: I think it would be allowed in both.  Naturally any members of `D` would be uninitialized (unless static storage duration in which case zero-initialized) and therefore the static member function would have to be careful not to use the uninitialized values.

Comment: @BenVoigt the text you quote is meant to be interpreted like this:  "Given that an object is beginning its lifetime, the exact moment it begins is when storage with the proper alignment and size is obtained [etc.]"  . It doesn't mean that obtaining storage for an object implies that an object was created.

Comment: @M.M: So you mean that if we take out the non-trivial constructor, the current code is UB, but this variation is legal?  `C c; c.memory.print(); new (&c.memory) D;` ?  That's ludicrous.  The plain meaning is that an object exists, live, as soon as storage for it is obtained.

Comment: @BenVoigt `C c; c.memory.print();` is UB since no object has been created. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644977/) for more detailed analysis

Comment: @M.M: The problem is that your interpretation requires time-travel. "Given that an object is beginning its lifetime, the exact moment it begins" <time travel happens> "when storage with the proper alignment and size is obtained". The storage can be obtained arbitrarily before placement-new, and placement-new undoubtedly causes an object to begin its lifetime. The only way out of your paradox without time travel is for the object to have been created along with the storage, and then the placement new creates a new object created in its place (destroying the old through re-use, which is allowed)

Comment: (And yes, I know that time-travel is allowed as a result of UB, but it isn't allowed as a result of valid well-defined code sequences)

Comment: @BenVoigt this is already addressed by TC's answer, I've no interest in rehashing those comments again everywhere that the issue comes up.  Anyway it is moot for this particular question since the standard explicitly says that a union member's lifetime does not begin in this case. (basic.life/1)